# Circle Packing Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, circles, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I have question related to circle-packing. The problem is to find the circle of minimum radius enclosing four non-overlapping circles of arbitrary radius. I have to write a program in C for this question but have not been able to find a formula for the radius of the enclosing circle. Any help appreciated.

For more understanding see this [link](http://www.palgrave-journals.com/jors/journal/v62/n11/full/jors2010157a.html)

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: Question is just find the minimum radius of Circle circumscribing four circle of unequal radius. Please see this [link](http://www.palgrave-journals.com/jors/journal/v62/n11/fig_tab/jors2010157f2.html#figure-title) for figure and some solution...But required a short approach/formula...

Comment: @jaywendt..Plz help me..

Comment: Regarding your "test cases": how can even one circle of radius 2500 be contained in a circle of radius 1837? I looked at the link you posted. To make sense of your question I think the radius of the enclosed circles would have to be smaller.

Comment: @daniel..Yes ur right..Test case are wrongly posted...

Comment: @Avinash: in that case the question is probably clear enough without the examples.

Comment: @daniel..Plz give me some solution to solve such problem..except that I posted...

Comment: @daniel..I do now..

Comment: @daniel..I want some simple approach to do the same..different from Paper..Because paper has solution for n circle and in my case only four. So, if I get some alternate solution based on some single hit formula then it great help for me...

Comment: @Avinash: now I think the problem is clear, and the link in your comment connects to a paper which actually does answer your question. It's a nontrivial optimization problem which is set out pretty clearly in the first set of equations in that paper. Perhaps someone with expertise in that area will address your question.

Comment: Waiting for someone to help.......

Answer (score 1):

Almost exactly a year before this answer was posted (6 August 2015) Mike Bostock encountered this problem while developing his [D3.js library](https://d3js.org), except that the number of circles was arbitrary and they could overlap. He made a solution that works in all these cases, which can be seen (and played around with) [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/29c534ff0b270054a01c).

The algorithm is a modification of [Welzl's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem#Linear-time_solutions) for finding the smallest enclosing circle of a set of points. The modifications that allow it to handle circles are, as explained in the bl.ocks.org link:

- The test for whether the next point is in the current smallest enclosing circle replaces the point with another circle, and is trivial to implement.
- The enclosing circle itself is tangent to two or three circles; its radius and position are calculated by any solution to the [problem of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius).

Hence the problem posed in the question, the smallest enclosing circle of four non-overlapping circles, can be solved very quickly on a computer.