# Packing of nodes in a circle

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

This is in a scenario of packing wireless transmitters in a circle with interference constraints. We would like to place $N$ nodes, transmitting at a fixed power $P_{T}$ in a circle of radius $R$. Each encounters interference from the $N-1$ others as per the power law:
$$
P_{Int,i} = \sum_{j \neq i} P_{T}d_{ij}^{-\alpha}
$$ 
where $d_{ij}$ is the distance between nodes $i$ and $j$. $\alpha$ is the path-loss exponent (usually between 2 and 4). What is the maximum number of nodes that can be placed in the circle, while obeying the interference constraint:
$$
P_{Int,i} \leq P_{Thresh}
$$
or, if there are any closed-form bounds on the answer.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118265/circle-packing-algorithm

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Thanks for the link. I am not sure how this problem would translate into the packing of circles (except for a trivial bound, I am not sure how else).

Comment: Probably not directly, I was just adding pointers for the passing by reader.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much that there is a closed-form solution.  Packing problems tend to be hard.  You might be able to get upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I should've asked for this in the question. Will add. Thank you !